# Spring Cloud Stream validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

How to perform validation with [Spring Cloud Stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) framework in message listeners using standard Spring annotation based validation?

Tried different cases, with `@Valid @Payload`for incoming object, tried method validation post processor with `@Validated` on entity, but it didn't help.

```
@StreamListener(MediaItemStream.ITEM_LIKED_CHANNEL)
public void handleLikeMessage(@Valid @Payload LikeInputDto like) {...
```

and

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

The best approach for now is just using of custom service for validation, but it looks not as wanted..

```
@Log4j2
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LikeStreamHandler {

    private MediaEventMessagingService mediaEventMessagingService;
    private ValidationService validationService;

    @StreamListener(MediaItemStream.ITEM_LIKED_CHANNEL)
    public void handleLikeMessage(LikeInputDto like) {
        validationService.validate(like);

        log.debug("Handling LIKE message: {}", like);
        mediaEventMessagingService.processLikeEvent(like);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new Feature of Spring Cloud Stream v2.1.0: [Issue on GitHub: "Add (javax.)Validation Support for Stream Listener"](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1382)