# Spring Cloud Stream validation (functional approach)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

There is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643216/spring-cloud-stream-validation) how to use `@Valid` annotation with spring-cloud-stream  library, there is even documentation how to do it in docs but in [October 6 2020](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/e3faae2091330a521f48b7df628acbc2597b41f4) `@StreamListener` approach was officially deprecated and example removed.

Old way:

```java
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
@SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
public VoteResult handle(@Valid Vote vote) {
  return votingService.record(vote);
}
```

New way:

```java
public Function<Vote, VoteResult> handle() {
  return vote -> votingService.record(vote);
}
```

My question is, how migrate this functionality using new functional model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do it manually, injecting a `Validator` instance into your component, then calling `validator.validate(vote)`:

```java
private final Validator validator;

public Function<Vote, VoteResult> handle() {
  return vote -> {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Vote>> constraints = validator.validate(vote);
    if (!constraints.isEmpty()) {
      // handle validation errors
    }
    votingService.record(vote);
  }
}
```

Same as [Spring Cloud Stream and Hibernate Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669961/spring-cloud-stream-and-hibernate-validator/73737747)